# Create a query cell which returns a true/false depending on query

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of items that get status updates daily, and I want to be able to see the status update of an item by just copy/pasting its name into a cell, and have a true/false return depending on item status, True=updated, False=not updated.

The status update is a date, so I was thinking of using IsNumber as a workaround to get a "True" value, then using the Query function to isolate all items with a date/status update ("select B where C = True").

The idea is to use this list as a "database" for the query cell, which returns a True value if item is in the list. But I don't know if it's possible to create a searchable query box in google sheets. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you somehow show true only when the date of update is today ? Can you set up an example spreadsheet with some realistic data and the expected outcome ?

Comment: Sure, I will set up an example spreadsheet and share later today. And to answer your question- nope, for my purpose it's enough to know that an item was updated at some point in time, i.e. received a status update vs. other items which have not yet received it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=isnumber(vlookup(B2,B:C,2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding, but how does this create a searchable query cell? Edit in response to JPV: above spreadsheet is similar to my example sheet.

Comment: Oh I understand, thank you. I want to see the True/False status of an item by typing the item name in a spreadsheet cell. I came across this blog where I think the writer is achieving what I want to do. http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/01/26/creating-query-forms-in-google-spreadsheets-sort-of/. Secondly, working on the problem some more, I am using the following to get a true/false depending on whether the item exists in the query function list: =(Isnumber(SEARCHB("Test String 3", G:G))).

Comment: You're right, much simpler to do than my long route :) Thank you!